# Understanding the guard function in do block

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, alternative-functor

I have the following type:

```
newtype Rep f a = Rep { runRep :: String -> f (String, a) }
```

The type `Rep f a` is a stateful computation that takes a String as the initial state and produces a `(String, a)` as the result of the computation. The result of the computation is wrapped in the functor `f`.

The monad instance for Rep is the following:

```
instance Monad f => Monad (Rep f) where 
   return x = pure x 
   Rep a >>= f = Rep $ \s -> do
    (s', xa) <- a s
    let (Rep f') = f xa
    (s'', xf) <- f' s'
    pure (s'', xf)
```

The alternative instance for Rep is the following:

```
instance (Monad f, Alternative f) => Alternative (Rep f) where 
    empty = Rep (const empty)
    Rep a <|> Rep b = Rep $ \s -> a s <|> b s
```

I also have the following function:

```
readCharacter :: (Alternative f, Monad f) => Rep f Char
readCharacter = Rep $ \s -> case s of
[] -> empty
(x:xs) -> pure (xs,x)
```

The above function takes a state and returns `empty` if the state is an empty list. If the state is not an empty list, it returns a tuple with the first element the modified state and the second a `Char`, wrapped in the functor `f`.

And I also have the following function and data type:

```
data Res = Nil | Character Char | Cop Res Res | Special [Res]

findmatch :: (Monad f, Alternative f) => String -> Rep f Res

findmatch (cs) = do
   x <- readCharacter
   guard (x `elem` cs)
   pure (Character x)
```

I am having trouble understanding how the above function works. It seems to me that for each character in the string `cs`, the `readCharacter` function is called. If the character returned by `readCharacter` is an element of the string `cs`, then the expression will evaluate to true. Suppose that the functor `f` is `Maybe` - then `guard (True)` will return a `Just ()`, and then `pure (Character x)` is returned.

However, I am not sure what happens when the guard expression evaluates to `False`. For example, assuming that the functor is `Maybe`, `guard False` will return `Nothing`. If `Nothing` is returned by `guard False`, is it the case that the overall `do block` will return `Nothing`? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: What is the instance of `Monad` for `Rep` here?

Comment: I have added the monad instance for Rep in the question.

Comment: Also, what is the `Alternative` instance for `Rep`? The short answer is, your definition of `>>=` is probably not defined for `empty :: Rep f Char`, meaning there is a pattern match failure which leads to `fail` short-circuiting the rest of the `do` block.

Comment: I have added the alternative instance for Rep as well.

Comment: As for your `Maybe` example, `guard False >> ... == Nothing >> ... == Nothing`; `>>` for `Maybe` ignores the right operand when the left operand is `Nothing`.

Comment: Just to clarify, did you use the >> operator between guard False and pure (Character x) due to fact that the result of guard False wasn't bound to a variable using <-, so there is no extracted value to pass to the next function in the do block?

Comment: Yes; `>>` itself is simply defined as `m >> k = m >>= \_ -> k`.

Comment: Also, am I correct in saying that the do block is executed for each character in the string cs?

Comment: No, iteration is not a feature of the `do` block, but rather the specific implementation of `>>=` for the list monad.